# FabricJS iText object's text not being changed on Android

Tags: fabricjs

I'm trying to edit an iText object's text through a modal that is supposed to replace the text already on canvas with the new one (this.textAndroid) on editing mode. It works fine on iPhone but for some reason it doesn't show the text changed on android. Keeps showing the old one. Has anyone encountered this problem?

```
editTextAndroid(obj){
  obj.set({ text: this.textAndroid });
  obj.exitEditing();
  this.canvas.renderAll();
  obj.initBehavior();
  store.commit('changeInteractionMode', 'DRAG');
},
```

Comment: Your text object is in editing mode while you adding the text?

Comment: @Durga yes, im calling this method on text:editing:entered

Comment: You need to exit before setting text.

Comment: @Durga It still doesn't work on Android. Works fine everywhere else

Comment: can you create a minimal snippet/fiddle with your code?

Comment: @Durga it's a little complicated to reproduce it in one minimal fiddle but the method above is the one used in this case, specifically this line  obj.set({ text: this.textAndroid });